# How to store values in a hashmap/Array to be compared to later

Tags: javascript

I need to loop through 1-100 potential values and check if the value appears once or twice and do certain things based off that. (The values will only appear 0,1,2 times). Is there a way I can store the values that I generate in an array or hashmap and compare new values that i generate versus the other ones already in the hashmap?

I appreciate the help!

edit: the values that i will be pulling are integers, so I was thinking i can sort all my values in my hashmap and then compare from there?

Comment: Hashmaps (or just objects, as they're typically called in JS) don't have any concept of being sorted (in JS). They are a set of key-value pairs, and you either directly access the value by knowing the key, or you iterate over the keys in a not-guaranteed order. Arrays, on the other hand, can be sorted, since order matters for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding you, you can just use JavaScript objects. What are you trying to do?

```
hash = {};

// Count the number of times each value occurs in the values array.
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (!hash[values[i]]) {
        hash[values[i]] = 1;
    } else {
        hash[values[i]] += 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always map an element to the number of times it appears. So if `5` appears `3` times, your map would be:

```
{ 5: 3 }
```

So every time you get a value, you update the map if it contains an entry, or create a new entry with a count of `1`:

```
var map = {};
function addValue(value) {
    if(!map[value]) {
        map[value] = 0;
    }

    map[value]++;
}
```

Then all you have to do is:

```
for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    addValue(values[i]);
}
```

As far as sorting, you can't rely on keys being sorted in JavaScript maps while you iterate. But you could do this:

```
var sortedKeys = Object.keys(map).sort();
```

And now you have an array of sorted keys.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using the Objects concept...

```
var obj = new Object();

function(val) {
    if (obj.val == undefined) {
        obj.val = 1;
    } else {
        obj.val++;
    }
}

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: `function(var val)` is not valid JavaScript for a function declaration (lose the `var`).

Comment: sorry do you explain @ajp15243 i dont understand wt u saying

Comment: You are declaring an anonymous function in your example code, but you are doing it incorrectly. You should not have `var` in your function parameters list, as that is not how JavaScript declares its function parameters. The signature should simply read `function(val) {...}`. Although, without a name, assignment to a variable, or immediate execution, that anonymous function is not reachable/executable.